# Mute all sounds on login

Tags: windows, audio

I love to listen to my music at work but to not disrupt my colleges I use my personal headphones. So when I leave I take them with me and when I want to use them I plug them in - no big deal. But most of the time I forget to mute Windows before I shut down so the next time I boot there are sounds played when I don't want them.

Is there a way to mute sounds on startup/shutdown? *(I don't mean the windows sounds for login/logout but sounds in general)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a software called "Auto Mute". I personally haven't tried it, but the description says it can mute your sound on logoff, suspend or shutdown.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Gonna give it a try